# C#,English and Arabic string direction

Tags: c#

I have arabic string and the alignment is correct (RTL) when all words in string are Arabic but when string contains Arabic and English words the string alignment not correct.
when userName is English the string alignment is not correct
By the way i tried this answer and didn't work

```
  string userName = "توم";
  string message = "يحب الورد";
  string fullString = string.Format("{0} {1}", userName, message);
  fullString is "توم يحب الورد" //correct result


  string userName = "Tom";
  string message = "يحب الورد";
  string fullString = string.Format("{0} {1}", userName, message);
  fullString is "Tom يحب الورد" //wrong result.
  fullString should be "يحب الورد Tom"  //This result is exactly what i need
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [incorrect right to left concatenation english and Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146491/incorrect-right-to-left-concatenation-english-and-arabic)

Comment: And though the dupe is similar, here you want to force the userName string to follow RTL rules (appearing at the right as the start of the string).  Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39147040/327083) you would substitute `LTR_EMBED = '\u202A'` for `RTL_EMBED = '\u202B'` and pad the `userName` string as in the example.

Comment: @J... Thank you so much for your effort . i followed your post and worked! but i still have one problem  that my string now looks "\u202bيحب الورد Tomu\202c". I tried to remove \u202b and u\202c but didn't work

Comment: What do you mean when you say your string "looks like" that - are you looking at it in the debugger?  The debugger will show the unicode formatting characters but they should not be displayed when rendered in an application or in any controls.

Comment: My project is Web API and the string shows like above in postman

Comment: It sounds like you need to ask a new question.